# windows api to create shortcut and put application in start menu

Tags: c++, windows, winapi

I have a client application in C++. For that I want to create a shortcut on the desktop and an entry in the start menu while installing. Is there any C++ windows api for that? I tried searching for it but couldn't find it. Can anyone tell me how it can be done?

Comment: Typically your install script takes care of that.  What installer are you using?

Comment: Don't write your install program in C++. Use a tool to build an install program.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan:: Any particular reason for that?

Comment: @Abhineet same reason you use an existing compiler instead of writing your own.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan:: :-) Understood

Answer (score 3):

You'll have to get your hands a bit dirty, and use COM to access the Shell. You can read here about [Shell Links](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa969393.aspx). Also, [this project](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/winsdk/makelink.aspx) might provide you the code you need.

To get the location of the desktop and the start menu folders, you can use the appropriate [System Variables](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms682653%28v=vs.85%29.aspx).